# How to solve $y''+y'/x+f(x)y=0$ using B.C.s $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, na.numerical-analysis

The term $f(x)$ is available numerically. It was curve fitted to some function of $x$. I've used dsolve in Matlab. It reported that solution can't be found. 
I tried solving the above equation using
finite differences with the derivative applied at the boundary using forward differences.
As I change my step size the solution takes a different form apart from increasing its amplitude over the domain of $x$.
Then implemented orthogonal collocation and orthogonal collocation on finite elements. The solution didn't converge. But when the term $1/x$ is removed from the ODE, the solution converges.

Thanks and regards,
Tilak

Answer (score 1):

The boundary conditions do not work. Write your equation as
$$
(x\,d/dx)^2 y + x^2 f(x) y = 0
$$
to see that you have a fundamental system $y_1$, $y_2$ with $y_1(x)
\sim 1$, $y_2(x) \sim \log x$ as $x\to+0$ (assuming that
$f$ is smooth up to $x=0$). So, $y(0)=0$ already implies that
$y\equiv0$.

Comment: You can get a solution with $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 1$, if you take $f(x) \sim -1/x^2$ as $x \to 0+$.  Of course these singularities at $0$ require special care when using numerical methods.

Comment: @ifw Please see equation 4.4 in   the below paper where it was solved  for the same boundary conditions https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/6AB7F50FBF65A5DED546C613E3B29895/S0022112003004749a.pdf/div-class-title-three-dimensional-vortex-breakdown-in-swirling-jets-and-wakes-direct-numerical-simulation-div.pdf

Comment: @Tilak The term $y'/x$ is $-y'/x$ (which matters!) according to Eq. (4.4) of this reference and, most of all, the coefficient $f$ becomes singular as $x\to+0$ (see also Robert's comment). If you expect a useful answer, you should specify those conditions precisely in your post.